# Problem constructing an iBeacon advertisment in Android

Tags: android, ibeacon

I am trying to simulate an iBeacon using BluetoothLeAdvertiser.
I have managed to scan and find iBeacons without any difficulty but when creating an iBeacon myself the advertising data sent out seems wrong.

The beacons I have found have the following format:
Byte 0 value: 0x02 Data length – 2 bytes
Byte 1 value: 0x01 Data type – flags
Byte 2 value: 0x06 LE and BR/EDR flag
Byte 3 value: 0x1a Data length – 26 bytes
Byte 4 value: 0xff Data type - manufacturer specific data
Byte 5 value: 0x4c Manufacturer data
Byte 6 value: 0x00 Manufacturer data
 .. etc

I tried to construct similar advertising data to simulate an iBeacon using AdvertiseData.Builder.addManufacturerData by constructing an array and copying the values above. However, when I send the advertisement data extra bytes having been added at the beginning:
0x1a 0xff 0x4c 0x00

I have notice the number of extra bytes and their values changing depending on how I set the Advertising settingsData. For example, 
AdvertiseData.Builder.setConnectable(true); adds another 3 bytes at the beginning of my Advertising data (As detected in BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback).

Is there a way to have absolute control over what the Advertiser sends out as data? I have checked https://github.com/AltBeacon/android-beacon-library/blob/master/src/main/java/org/altbeacon/beacon/BeaconTransmitter.java, but that is doing more or less what I'm doing as far as I can tell.
Using Bluetooth 5 on Android 9.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Android BLE Advertising APIs do not give you full control over the transmitted packet.**  A "manufacturer advertisement" frame starts with a length byte, then 0xff to indicate it is a manufacturer type, followed by the two byte manufacturer code.

So when you see 0x1a 0xff 0x4c 0x00, you only have partial control over those bytes.  The 0xff is fixed based on the advertisement type you are sending.   0x1a is the length of your packet (which you can partially control based on how many bytes you put into the advertisement) and 0x4c 0x00 you can control by setting the manufacturer code.

The remaining bytes are your payload, and you have full control of them up to the limited packet size.  Any proceeding bytes before the length (0x1a in your case) are flags headers, and Android gives you no control over those.

Comment: Thanks David. Your sample code has been a big help as has that clarification. Presumably it is up to the searching application to parse the advertising data and figure out if it is an iBeacon advert based on manufacturer id and type data field etc? Apologies if you have answered this before.

Comment: Yes, it is up to the searching application to determine that.  The reference implementation of this is Apple's CoreLocation on iOS.  Unfortunately, it is closed source.  But it's generally understood what it is doing -- it is looking for a manufacturer advertisement with the apple company code, the 0x0215 iBeacon type identifier, and enough bytes following that  (normally 21 more bytes that indicate the identifiers one byte for the measured power).